# Struts2 JQuery DatePicker: set maxDate to today

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I want the `maxDate` to be set to the current date.

I've tried with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574249/struts2-jquery-datepicker-set-past-date-range-by-maxdate-mindate) but I still have problems.

Here is my code:

```
<sj:datepicker id = "dob"        
             name = "dateOfBirth" 
            label = "Date Of Birth" 
      changeMonth = "true"  
       changeYear = "true"    
        yearRange = "1980" 
          maxDate = "0"      
         readonly = "true" />
```

Comment: Thankx a lot Andrea helping to solve my problem. Calendar is displaying correctly by using above struts2 datepicker code and also i'm setting maxDate="0" with the same code but its not hiding future dates.  Solution ==> calendar should display until today's date and upcoming/future dates should be disabled. When i use timepicker="true" with the same code its working fine for maxDate="0" and disbaling future date. But i need solution with attached code maxDate="0" should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 jquery datepicker - set past date range by maxDate & minDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574249/struts2-jquery-datepicker-set-past-date-range-by-maxdate-mindate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```xml
<sj:datepicker 
    ....
    maxDate="%{new java.util.Date()}"
/>
```

or return `new Date()` from a getter, and use the code in the other answer you linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrea its working fine now with your code. Would u please help me to solve my another problem because i got stuck from past two days. I need Solution using struts2 jquery datepicker how to enable only particular dates in a calendar remaining all other dates should be disabled.Even i tried with onCompleteTopics and onBeforeShowDayTopics using struts2 jquery datepicker. Without using struts2 i can able to get the solution  here==> http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/4/. Same thing i need using struts2 jquery datepicker. Please please help me to solve my problem.